# How to programmatically submit, publish and upgrade apps to various mobile app stores?

Tags: android, ios, app-store

My question is simple: is there a way to totally automate the process to publish (and/or upgrade) a massive number of apps to AppStore and Google Play?
How do they do companies like MobileAppLoader, appbreeder, AppMakr and the like to publish, upgrade and manage their massive number of apps in the different stores?
I cannot think they do it manually everytime, there must be a programmatically way to do that kind of things. But how?

Comment: Havn't thought of it, nice one. But I don't think there might be any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the reason some opt for **MobileWeb** apps. They donot require to update through an app store.

See the link for more info:

http://sixrevisions.com/web-applications/building-mobile-web-apps-the-right-way-tips-and-techniques/

Answer (score 1):

The is no way for a developer to directly publish an app in the iOS App store.  Only Apple can allow publication after reviewing the apps submitted to them.

Xcode on a Mac is used to submit apps to Apple for review.  And Xcode can be scripted by Automater or AppleScript.  These scripts could be potentially launched from unix scripts or chron jobs or the shell command-line, since Mac OS X is a Unix OS.

Comment: I do not intend to circumvent the Apple store review process at all, just to automate the submission part. About automating the compilation part you are right, but the submisison process is a differnt beast. You have to integrate some actions to be done in xcode with others to be done online on the iTunesConnect, and this is the problem even because if you study their site it seams a mixture of ajax and static content, so it's hard to make a script.

Answer (score 0):

To the AppStore and Google Play there isn't, mainly because if there was, it would be abused by spammers.

Now, for everything, but getting the applications to the stores, you can automate it.

Here is one example that would also work with Android.

http://nachbaur.com/blog/how-to-automate-your-iphone-app-builds-with-hudson

If you can commit changes, and at the end your automated process has a beta test version ready, then you just code, the testing/building/publishing to beta site is automated, you can handle many applications, more easily.

Comment: Currently google does have an API for uploading APK's to the play store.